# Running a function for every present turtle from each of the turtle's perspectives

Tags: simulation, netlogo

From each of the turtle's perspectives, I have to run a function for a turtle to decide which turtle it will assign as it's "buddy".

Right now I have the code below but it doesn't achieve the effect.

```
foreach sort other turtles [
      ask ? [
        if Smin < Sim myself ? and self != ? [
        ]
      ]
 ]
```

In C/Java it would've been simple, just a simple for loop and then that's it. Apparently I am having a hard time understanding NetLogo's foreach function and the integration of '?' in looping. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from the code sample you posted what exactly you are trying to do.

Some things that may help:

- Unless you want to address your turtles in a specific order, it's usually not necessary to  use `foreach`. Just doing `ask other turtles [ ... ]` can replace the whole `foreach sort other turtles [ ask ? [ ... ] ]`.
- Given that you are inside an `ask ?` block, `self != ?` will *always* be false, and thus, so will the `and` clause of your `if`. The code inside your inner block is never reached.
- `myself` refers the agent from an "outer" ask block (e.g., in `ask x [ ask y [ ... ] ]`, `self` would be `y` and `myself` would be `x`). Neither `myself` nor `self` is affected by `foreach`, and `?` is not affected by `ask`.

My guess is that maybe you just want:

```
ask other turtles [
  if Smin < Sim myself self [
  ]
]
```

But I can't know for sure, especially since I have no idea what `Smin` and `Sim` are. If you post more detail, maybe we can help you further.

Finally: NetLogo code usually ends up being much simpler than the equivalent C/Java code, but you must learn to embrace the "NetLogo way". Thinking in Java/C and then trying to translate in NetLogo will usually lead one astray.

Comment: I see. I am actually trying to convert a pseudo code I read, and my silly mind keeps relating pseudo codes to C (C is the first programming language I learned, thats probably why). I'll try if I can post the pseudo-code here in order to clarify my question.